# Update text of Visio Diagrams using POI in Word document

Tags: apache-poi, visio, xwpf

I have a word document (XWPFDocument). It contains some visio diagrams.
I want to update the text of these diagrams dynamically.
Can I do that using Apache POI?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. According to Apache POI API docs, there is only read support for the Visio XML document:

http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xdgf/usermodel/XmlVisioDocument.html

> public class XmlVisioDocument
>   extends POIXMLDocument
>   This is your high-level starting point for working with Visio XML documents (.vsdx). Currently, only read support has been implemented, and the API is not mature and is subject to change. For more information about the visio XML format (with an XSD 1.0 schema), you can find documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh645006(v=office.12).aspx That document lacks in some areas, but you can find additional documentation and an updated XSD 1.1 schema at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj684209(v=office.15).aspx Each provides different details, but the SharePoint reference has better documentation and is more useful.

Additionally, from reading the API, it doesn't look like it would be possible to access the Visio diagram embedded in the Word document.